# Char* function Never Return value

Tags: c

I'm a newbie of C. Here I write a function to parse http post from browser. Here is my code:

```
char* HTTP_POST_GET_BODY(char* HttpPost){

     char* HttpPostBody = strstr(HttpPost,"\r\n\r\n");
     HttpPostBody = HttpPostBody + 4;
     if(strcmp(HttpPostBody,"\r\n\r\n") != 0 && strcmp(HttpPostBody,"") != 0){
         return HttpPostBody;
     }
     else{
        char* HttpPostBody_IE;
        HttpPostBody = strstr(HttpPost,"::");
        char* HttpPostBodyEnd = strstr(HttpPost,"HTTP/1.1");
        int body_length = HttpPostBodyEnd - HttpPostBody;
        strncpy(HttpPostBody_IE,HttpPostBody+2,body_length-2);
        return HttpPostBody_IE;
     }

}
```

So basically, if the procedure goes in the "else" it should return a char pointer to caller. I check the debugger. HttpPostBody_IE has a value but when it return it is a null string.

```
char* http_body = HTTP_POST_GET_BODY(recieve_buffer);
```

Anyone has an idea about it?

Comment: Try to think about `char* HttpPostBody_IE;` What is pointing this pointer....? Which is the scope of the pointer?

Comment: What do you mean? Is it because I didnt allocate space for it?

Comment: I try to malloc a space to it but If I free it then it cant be return. If I just do the return and the memory is not freeing

Comment: Why do you want to free a memory that you want to use later?.... Non sense. `malloc` it and free it as far as `http_body` is not more required to be used

Comment: Braces '{' and '}' define "scope". Variables declared within a "scope" will be  "out of scope" outside the braces. Typically such variables reside in stack or registers, the contents of which may be discarded when you leave the "scope".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the pointer-variable `HttpPostBody_IE` but never allocate memory for it.
The call to `strncpy(....)` should create a core dump.
Try this:

```
int body_length = HttpPostBodyEnd - HttpPostBody;
HttpPostBody_IE = (char*)malloc(body_length+1);
strncpy(HttpPostBody_IE,HttpPostBody+2,body_length-2);
return HttpPostBody_IE;
```

Of course, make sure the caller of this functions releases the allocated memory afterwards.
You have a problem in case the function returns from within the `if` statement. This because no memory is allocated in that case.

You might resolve it this way:

```
static char HttpPostBody_IE[BIG_ENOUGH_FOR_ANY_SOURCE];
if (....)
{
  ...
}
else
{
  ...
  strncpy(HttpPostBody_IE, ...);
  return (HttpPostBody_IE);
}
```

Please notice that in this way the variable needs to be static.

Comment: ...and check `malloc` return....and do not cast `malloc` return in [tag:c]

Comment: ye but how i gonna free this space?

Comment: @LPs What do you mean do not cast malloc return in c?

Comment: free(...); It may cause problems; I just edited my answer

Comment: ye. I know free(...). but What can i do if i dont wanna free the space outside the function.

Comment: @Pwan `malloc` return `void *` that is fine for whatever pointer using [tag:c]. Take a look [at this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Pwan So do not free it. Free it at the end of program. What's the problem.

Comment: @LPs: what if the program is running for ever in background? You get an out-of-memory error.

Comment: If the function is called more that 1 time, just use realloc since the first call amd that's all. BTW I meant: if you want a global scoped variable declare a global scoped variable in module. Declaring a local static variable to be exported is non-sense and source of future misunderstanding.